# Duda Activitys Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

vengo buscando consejo porque no se como puedo gestionar mi problema y me gustaria saber de vuestro consejo para saber como atajarlo.

Tengo un Grid view con varios botones, estos botones lanzan diferentes fragments o activitys, dependiendo del que pulses. Una de estos botones que pulsas lanza una activity de confirmación de licencia del programa ( muy sencilla, un par de edit text y un boton )

Lo que quiero hacer es que antes de entrar en esta activity te lance un fragment o una activity (lo que me recomendeis que es mejor) pidiendome una contraseña para continuar, he creado ya mi .xml para la peticion de contraseña y tengo localizado donde se lanza la activity al pulsar el boton.

¿Como me recomendais hacer esto? ¿Como puedo hacer para lanzar una activity y si se confirma la contraseña lance una segunda activity?

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El estado de si hay que pedir la clave o no (si el último login todavía está vigente) lo guardarías en `SharedPreferences`. Acá tenés que determinar que es lo que vas a guardar para que te indique si hay o no que pedir la clave, puede ser desde un boolean para una clave por unica vez, una fecha y hora de vencimiento, un token, o una combinación de estas cosas.

Partiendo de esto, al estar en `SharedPrefrences`, queda disponible para cualquier Activity, y también para cualquier Fragment.

Pero implementando el control como un `Activity` separado, se logra una mejor separación de responsabilidades, dado que el control lo haría el Activity que pide la clave y recién si está verificado el ingreso correcto de la misma, llamaría al `Activity` real que se quiere ejecutar.

En otras palabras, si el `Activity` que hace el control, no valida la clave, el `Activity` que se quiere proteger, no llega a ejecutarse.

Entonces, en el `GridView` lo que en realidad estarás colcoando es el `Activity` que hace el control de ingreso de clave.

Si se verifica que hace falta ingresar la clave, muestras el formulario. Si la clave se valida correctamente, actualizas `SharedPreferences`, y lanzas el `Activity` protegido con un `Intent`.

Y si no se valida vuelves al `Activity` del `GridView`.

Lo más probable es que el `Activity` que hace el control lance el `Intent` para abrir el `Activity` protegido desde `onCreate()`.

Esto da un error si se quiere hacer en el mismo `Thread` que está ejecutando el `onCreate()`, por eso se suele hacer utilizando un `Handler`.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityParaIniciar.class);
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ActivityActual.this.startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
}, 100);
```

**ActivityParaIniciar**:  es la activity protegida
**ActivityActual**: es la activity que realiza el control
*Nota: Es importante el finish() para que al volver no se vuelva a este activity.*